# Using Remix run, how do you get returned errors from a useFetcher form submission back into your form?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I am trying to use useFetcher to submit a form and return any errors.

I have a form component on a route: `routes/form`

I have an api route for processing the submitted form: `routes/api/process_form`

As expected, when I submit the form and get a response it reloads the 'loader' from the form route, however, as I am submitting the data to the API route, how do I get the response data back to the form loader?

- Do I have to hack it together with sessions?
- Is the solution to always submit the form to the parent route?

or

- Is there a better way???

Answer (score 1):

The initial `action` and subsequent *revalidation* are two *separate* requests. Remix doesn't *pass data* from the action to your loader.

You can use `session.flash()`, though. This allows you to set a value in the session that will be removed on subsequent access. So set the value in your action and read it in your loader.

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/utils/sessions#sessionflashkey-value

Comment: thanks as always for your help!.. I don't think I explained myself very well. The answer appears to be that I don't need to pass the data from the api to the form's loader at all, it can simply be accessed through: const myFetcher=useFetcher();  and then in the jsx: myFetcher.data.XYZ

Comment: Ah, I see. Sometimes when learning a new framework, finding the right words to express what you're asking is difficult. It usually helps if you show code, as that typically includes the context of your particular use case. Anyway, glad you were able to figure it out.